# possible to cache a table in sqlalchemy to not query database in specific use case?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a use case where I am running a python script constantly updating a specific column on a table in a database.  The script is like the following:

```
while True:
    events = load_events()
    for event in events:
        team_1 = event.team_1
        team_2 = event.team_2
        dd = datetime.strptime(event.gametime, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z")
        begin = dd - timedelta(hours=4)
        end = dd + timedelta(hours=4)

        db_event = session.query(SportEvent).filter(and_(
            SportEvent.home_team.contains(event.team_1),                                      
            SportEvent.away_team.contains(event.team_2),
            SportEvent.game_time.between(begin, end))).first()
        if db_event.e_id != event.event_id:
            setattr(db_event, 'e_id', event.event_id)
    session.commit()
```

My problem is that each loop takes far longer than is acceptable because I am updating 100k events.  I want to implement some sort of snapshot or cache at the start of each loop so each query to `SportEvent` doesn't actually produce a query on the database, but rather just  check against the cache.  (I understand the risks of this and they are acceptable for my use case in how this table is updated/accessed as a whole).  How can I implement something like this?

```
class SportEvent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'sport_events'

    id = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    sport_id = Column(String)
    league_id = Column(String)
    away_team = Column(String)
    home_team = Column(String)
    game_time = Column(DateTime)
    dk_id = Column(String)
    fd_id = Column(String)
    cs_id = Column(String)
    bm_id = Column(String)

    def __init__(self, home_team=None,
                 away_team=None,
                 game_time=None, sport_id=None, league_id=None):
        self.id = uuid.uuid4()
        self.home_team = home_team
        self.away_team = away_team
        self.game_time = game_time
        self.sport_id = sport_id
        self.league_id = league_id
        self.dk_id = ""
        self.fd_id = ""
        self.cs_id = ""
        self.bm_id = ""
```

Comment: How many teams are there total?

Comment: @flakes teams are < 200 total

Comment: Can you also post the Table class for `SportEvent`? Need to see the type on the columns

Comment: Whats the nominal case when updating the event id? What percentage of the event_ids are typically updated out of the 100k?

Comment: @flakes Updated to include `SportEvent` I also included an additional datetime filter I use (left it out initially to simplify my question, but since that will affect query performance I added it back)

Comment: @flakes < 1%.  ( I just need to catch anything that changes near instant)

Comment: You're also doing a contains lookup on the team name which is expensive. Is there anyway you could format the team name returned from the `load_events` to exactly match what is used in the database?

Comment: Unfortunately no.  My queries take less than a ms to execute on the database, so I don't think it's an issue from that perspective.  Just the fact that I need to make a query instead of some local dictionary lookup or something is extremely expensive for my use case(every second this data is delayed there is an impact).

Comment: @flakes Doing a small test of 30 items.  The queries take 2 seconds to execute in the python script, while on the service side, each query is  <1ms to execute.  The problem is the actual overhead of submitting a query so many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you're experiencing here is the cost per round trip from your service to your database. Depending on how many records need to be returned there are some options.

> Note, without a deeper understanding of the data provided, these queries might not be optimal.

The most obvious one is doing bulk queries. Say that the time of updates are all around the same time. We could do something like this:

```
begin = None
end = None
for event in events:
    gametime = datetime.strptime(event.gametime, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z")
    if not begin or gametime < begin:
        begin = gametime
    if not end or gametime > end:
        end = gametime 
begin = begin - timedelta(hours=4)
end = end + timedelta(hours=4)

records = session.query(SportEvent).filter(
    SportEvent.game_time.between(begin, end)
).all()
```

Now when looping you can consult the data you already queried.

```
for event in events:
    team_1 = event.team_1
    team_2 = event.team_2
    dd = datetime.strptime(event.gametime, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z")
    begin = dd - timedelta(hours=4)
    end = dd + timedelta(hours=4)

    db_event = next(
        (
            record
            for record in records
            if (
                team_1 in record.home_team
                and team_2 in record.away_team
                and begin < record.game_time < end
            )
        ),
        None
    )
    if db_event and db_event.e_id != event.event_id:
        db_event.e_id = event.event_id

session.commit()
```

Again, a better answer requires knowing more about the event data and how it can be optimized to limit the results returned. Say there are only specific teams that are played- you could do one bulk query and a loop for each team.

Basically you need to look at the commonalities in your data and attempt to do the least amount of calls to the database as possible.

Also note, most DBs have a maximum limit on the number of parameters in the query, in the case of PostgresQL that's 64,000 which is below your total query requirements.